# Replace multiple lines between two pattern matches that are variable substituted

Tags: sed

I'm attempting to replace some text inside a file that spans multiple lines. There is a beginning pattern and an ending pattern to be matched.

```
<User darthvader>
    home    /deathstar/
    lightsaber    red
</User>
```

Begin pattern

```
<User darthvader>
```

End pattern

```
</User>
```

Replace everything in between. There will be multiple different users in this file using the same format.

I need to use variables and these need to be expanded. I think this is where it starts to not work for me. I think there may also be an issue with the whitespace between `<User` and `darthvader`.

Take the following example;

```
BEGIN
    home    /deathstar/
    lightsaber    red
END
```

If I use this sed command

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_TO_EDIT="/file.txt"

sed -e '/BEGIN/{ N; s/BEGIN.*END/MAY THE FORCE BE WITH YOU/ }' ${FILE_TO_EDIT} >${FILE_TO_EDIT}.tmp && mv ${FILE_TO_EDIT}{.tmp,}
```

This gives me

```
BEGIN
MAY THE FORCE BE WITH YOU
END
```

So I know I'm on the right track. But as soon as I try to do something like

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_TO_EDIT="/file.txt"
USER="darthvader"
BEGIN="<User ${USER}>"
END="</User>"
REPLACE="Booyah!"

sed -e "/${BEGIN}/{ N; s/${BEGIN}.*${END}/${REPLACE}/ }" ${FILE_TO_EDIT} >${FILE_TO_EDIT}.tmp && mv ${FILE_TO_EDIT}{.tmp,}
```

Nothing seems to work. I've tried double quotes, changing the delimiter I'm just not having any luck here. I've looked at numerous examples on here but not one of them seems to address variable substitution at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i'.bak' -ne '\#'"$BEGIN"'#{p;:a;n;\#'"$END"'#!ba;i\'"$REPLACE" -e '};p' file
```

Use the `-i` option to make a backup of the original file. Use the `-n` option to suppress automatic printing of the pattern space. Use the `-e` options to allow the sed commands to occupy a single line.

The normal delimiter for regexp is the `/` character, however the bash variables may contain it so use an alternative (in this case the `#` has been chosen).

If the current line contains the string in `$BEGIN`, print it, and loop until the string in `$END` is the current line. Insert the string(s) in `$REPLACE` and print all other lines (including the line containing `$END`).

If the `$REPLACE` contains multiple lines, each line but the last will need to end in `\`, an alternative is to place the contents of replace in a file and use the following solution.

```
sed -i'.bak' -ne '\#'"$BEGIN"'#{p;:a;n;\#'"$END"'#!ba;e cat '"$FILE"' -e '};p' file
```

Where `$FILE` now contains the replacements, however since this uses the `e` command (which calls the `cat` command) the `$FILE` variable will need to be exported first e.g.

```
cat <<\!>replacementFile.txt
foo
bar
baz
!

export FILE="replacementFile.txt"
```